# How to disable specific JS file for a specific PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I am loading `jquery.js` in my footer file but it conflicts with the contact form's JS files. So I have to disable `jquery.js` only for the contact page.

I have following code but it is not working. How can I do it?

```
<script>$("script[src='http://www.example.com/js/jquery.js']").remove()</script>
```

Comment: Does your page contain code that calls jQuery functions? You will also need to remove those function calls, or you will get "function does not exist" errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to conditionally load a script, rather than to remove it after it's loaded.

Conditional loading goes like this:

1. test for presence of a conflicting function
2. if no conflict found, load the script into `<body>`

To test for the presence of a conflicting script, you can see if one of its functions is loaded. Let's say your conflicting script has a function `naughtyFn()`. This code will load jQuery only if `naughtyFn()` doesn't exist:

```js
// load jQuery, unless conflicting script exists
function loadJQ(conflictFName) {
  if (typeof window[conflictFName] === 'function') {
    return alert(`can't load jQuery, conflicts with ${conflictFName}`);
  }
  // create script tag and load into <head>
  const jqScript = document.createElement('script');
  jqScript.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js';
  document.body.appendChild(jqScript);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`window.jQuery: ${window.jQuery}`);
  }, 1000);
}

// load a conflicting script
function loadConflict() {
  const conflictScript = document.createElement('script');
  conflictScript.innerHTML = 'function naughtyFn() {}';
  document.body.appendChild(conflictScript);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`window.naughtyFn: ${window.naughtyFn}`);
  }, 1000);


}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="loadConflict();">Load conflicting script</button>
  <button onclick="loadJQ('naughtyFn');">Try to load jQuery</button>
</body>
```

Of course, in order for the conflict test to work, the `naughtyFn` must already be loaded. Therefore, it's a good idea to wait until `window.onload` to perform this conflict test:

```js
window.onload = () => {
   loadJQ('naughtyFn');
};
```